# AngularJS ng-grid catch edit event

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I am using Controller as Alias feature of an Angular.
I want to attach edit trigger with the grid. However, I don't know the rightly syntax that I should use:

Here is the code that I have:

```
function CodeLibrary($scope, dataservice, logger) {
        var vm = this;



        vm.gridOptions = {
            data: 'cl.library',
            showFilter : true,
            enableColumnResize : true,
            enableRowSelection: true,


            width: 'auto',
            plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],
            columnDefs: [{field:'id', displayName:'ID', width: '50'},
                {field:'key',  enableCellEdit: true, displayName:'KEY'},
                {field:'label',enableCellEdit: true,displayName:'Label'},
                {field:'value', enableCellEdit: true, displayName:'Value'}]
        };

        vm.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(event) {
            //console.log(event.targetScope.gridId);
        });

}
```

The error I am getting it as:

> [NG-Modular Error] undefined is not a function

Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

I have tried with vm.$scope.$on as well as $scope.$on....!

Comment: You will have to use `$scope.$on`. You wrote that you have tried it, but it should be working.

Comment: @tasseKATT Thank you I will try again however the $on is returning me null. Do I need to inject any directive ?

Comment: @tasseKATT No luck mate it is still the same i.e. $scope.$on is null! I don't know if I am missing any injection statement.

Comment: Can you try to replicate it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/npyfPMsoogppR22dAVkQ?p=preview